# Unable to build GUI from the code from PyQt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I made a GUI file from pyqt designer,which i converted to .py file.but when i load that .py code in my IDE (Pycharm and sublime text),and i try to run it,it runs without errors,but the physical aspect of GUI isn't loaded,i tried a custom code from the internet,which worked great,GUI shows up when i run that code. i will give simpler code than the one i'm currently working on,as it seems all of the code generated from pyqt designer doesn't work at all for me regarding its physical aspect.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 91, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 113, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**1.** Assuming you have used the following command:

```
pyuic5 your_filename.ui -o your_filename.py
# or 
# pyuic5 your_filename.ui > your_filename.py
```

That command does not generate a window object or call the show method so the window is not displayed, you must use option `-x`:

```
pyuic5 your_filename.ui -o your_filename.py -x
```

**2.** Add the code that invokes an object:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 91, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 113, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: no way...
i was taught to convert with this terminal command "pyuic5 filename.ui > filename.py", the terminal command you gave with -x at the end works like a charm. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Hitsugaya do not use `>`, it can bring you problems, instead use `-o`

Comment: will mark the answer as correct.
Thanks again for it.